# P symbol on outgoing changes in Synchronize view eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I did some changes to files on file system and did a sync with SVN from my eclipse workspace and noticed this 'p' symbol on some outgoing changes. Never seen this before and confused what it means and when it is shown.

[image]

Did google search but could not find anything. I just intend to know what it means and in what scenarios it occurs.

Any info is much appreciated.

Comment: It may not be a decorator from Subclipse  - see [this guide](http://www.rorycullen.com/blog/2009/07/guide-to-subclipse-decorator-icons/) which doesn't show any such overlay. What sort of change(s) did you make to that file?

Comment: @alroc : I replaced that `build.properties` file with another on the file system and then refreshed and synchronized through eclipse. Changes included a couple of lines commented, one removed and few added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is way after the fact, but I was looking for the answer to this today as well.

I found the answer [here](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/workspace_synch.php).

A properties change icon means, that the properties of local or repository's resource were changed.